# No TV-Out on Windows 7 with Nvidia Geforce 9400GT

Tags: windows-7, tv, nvidia-geforce, tv-out

I have Windows 7 x64 and a Nvidia Geforce 9400GT video card. I have connected my TV (SANSUI LCT40SD SAKURA) to my computer/video card with S-Video.

When I try to set up multiple displays in Nvidia Control Panel, I can't find the TV. I have only my normal screen "LG  W1934" which is enabled.

I have tried to use rigorous display detetion but it is still not recognizing my TV.

How can I fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried detecting it in the Windows 7 Display screen (right-click Desktop -> Screen Resolution)? And make sure your cable is good and not loose.

Comment: It is connected well and the cable is new and worked in XP. Nothing in "Screen Resolution"

Comment: Have you tried using the projector settings instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be the same bug I'm dealing with on Linux and Windows 7.  If it is, you should be able to make it detect by installing the 181.71 driver version from Nvidia.  If that gets it working, please file a bug report about this to Nvidia to help it get fixed sooner.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that it was connected on startup.  If not, try rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the connector is S-Video - it looks like S-Video and S-Video might even fit, but in the box there should be a component breakout cable.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue I ran into with 7 and S-video out was that 7 didn't like having both the TV on S-video and a monitor hooked up via VGA at the same time.

I ended up disconnecting the VGA and going only S-Video for now.

When I need to do any maintainence, I remote in from my laptop via LogMeIn free.